# migrate logins and password from sql 2000 to sql2005

Tags: sql-server

transfer logins from sql 2000 to 2005/2008:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133 (method2) works pretty good, however it doesn't transfer login's status (i.e. denied) nor the server level role membership, is there a script that covers these things?

What's the best way to verify a sql authenticated login's password on the source and destination server is the same? the source server is 2000, the destination server can be sql 2005 or sql 2008

Answer (score 1):

The code in Method 2 should do the trick, provided that you pass in the @include_db and 
@include_role parameters of the sp_help_revlogin_2000_to_2005 procedure to 1.  When it creates the output are you seeing the dynamic SQL which calls the sp_addsrvrolemember?  To have NT logins created as a DENY you'll need to remove the double dash "--" from before the sp_denylogin commands.